# Unable to connect to Microsoft band from Background Task

Tags: microsoft-band

I'm using MS Band SDK version **1.3.10518**, when I try to init the band client from **Background Task** I got:

> BACKGROUNDTASKHOST.EXE' has exited with code 1

The crash happens after the following line of code:

```
Dim bands = Await Microsoft.Band.BandClientManager.Instance.GetBandsAsync()
```

I'm able to connect to the band from the main application on windows phone 8.1 developer preview.

Band Build Version: *10.3.3213.0 09 R*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution related to Await in the Sub Run, the solution consists of using : taskInstance.GetDeferral

```
Public Async Sub Run(taskInstance As Background.IBackgroundTaskInstance) Implements Background.IBackgroundTask.Run
        Dim deferral = taskInstance.GetDeferral
        Dim bands = Await Microsoft.Band.BandClientManager.Instance.GetBandsAsync
          'Other work ...
            End Using
       deferral.Complete()
    End Sub
```

In addition you need to get user consent from the main application as follow:

```
bandClient.SensorManager.HeartRate.GetCurrentUserConsent
```

Thanks for: [HttpClient GetAsync fails in background task on Windows 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13078635/httpclient-getasync-fails-in-background-task-on-windows-8)